# Evaluating integral with weird limits

Tags: calculus

How do I evaluate this:
$$ \int_{h(t_0)}^{h(t_1)} a(t) \frac{dh}{dt} dt $$ where $$ h(t)=a(t)b(t) $$

Through integration by parts, I get:
$$ h(t)a(t)|_{h(t_0)}^{h(t_1)}-\int_{h(t_0)}^{h(t_1)} h(t) \frac{da}{dt} dt $$
How do i evaluate $$h(t)a(t)|_{h(t_0)}^{h(t_1)}$$

Comment: Try integration by parts.

Comment: Could you please tell me a bit more about the problem: where did it come from and why are you working on it? I am finding it very interesting but I'm going round in circles a bit and I'm starting to wonder if there's any assurance that a good solution exists.

Comment: It's from physics. Energy is $\int_{p_0}^{p_1}v\mathrm{d}p$ I am considering the case where both mass and velocity are changing. Mass doesn't have to depend on velocity, just for fun :>

Comment: I preferred to post it here as I want to use this type of integral for other things as well.